# Check wheter submitting value is in array?

Tags: php, forms

I have recently read an article that said, that you should never trust user in the sending data.

So let's say that I have following form inputs:

```
<label for="input1">Answer 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer1" id="input1" />
<label for="input2">Answer 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer2" id="input2" />
<label for="input3">Answer 3</label>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="answer3" id="input3" />
```

Is it okay to check whether posted answer is inside aray with answers:

```
$question1_answers = array("answer1", "answer2", "answer3");
$answer1 = $_POST['question1'];
if ( in_array($answer1, $question1_answers) ) {
    echo "OK!";
} else {
    echo "Please select proper answer!";
}
```

Or maybe above code is unnecessary and I should simply read `$_POST['question1']` and it will be enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it okay to check whether posted answer is inside aray with answers:

Yes! That is very good practice to validate a radio button value like that. The article you read is correct, you should not blindly trust user supplied data.

Answer (score 2):

for your situation its safe and enough. How I guess, that post was about sql injection, cross-site-scripting or something like that. You can read about sql injecition here :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

and about cross-site-scripting here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Answer (score 1):

Both way are correct. But I recommend the first way which you have posted.